# Adding every value from database to itself

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to add every value from database to itself like my value name in database is task_time I want to add **task_time** to **task_time** ( **totalTime = task_time + task_time + ... + taks_time** )

```
There is how I get data.
 function getEndTasks() {
        $http.get('db_files/endTasksDB.php').then(function(response) {
            $scope.dates = response.data;
            console.log($scope.dates);
        })
    }
```

Console log looks like

> Array[10] 0 : Object 1 : Object 2 : Object 3 : Object 4 : Object 5 :
>   Object 6 : Object 7 : Object 8 : Object 9 : Object

Object 0:

```
Object
$$hashKey:"object:60"
deadline:"2017-02-28"
dept:"test"
id:"1"
priority:null
status:"Closed"
task:"test"
task_end:"2017-03-02 10:57:51"
task_start:"2017-02-27 14:45:53"
task_time:"83"
total_time:"null"
username:"Nelson"
```

This is what I tried.

```
 $scope.total = response.data.map(function(item) {
                var totalTime = 0;

                for (var i=0; i<(item.task_time).length;i++){
                    totalTime = item.task_time[i];
                    totalTime += totalTime;
            item.total_time = totalTime;
            console.log("total time: " +item.total_time);
                    }
                return item;
            })
```

I don't have any error but console log shows something like:

> total time: 88 total time: 33 total time: 99 total time: 00 etc

and my table where I want to display it:

```
<table md-table>
    <thead md-head md-order="sort.order">
        <tr md-row>
            <th md-column>Spółka</th>
            <th md-column>Łączny czas</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody md-body>
        <tr md-row md-select="totalTime" md-on-select="" md-auto-select ng-repeat="totalTime in total | orderBy:sort.order | filter:search">
            <td md-cell>{{ totalTime.dept }}</td>
            <td md-cell>{{ totalTime.total_time }} godzin</td>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: why don't you do it with mysql directly?

Comment: I wouldn't use a map... declare a variable,  use forEach to iterate through the data, adding value to assigned var and at the end you'll have your total - but as mentioned above, just doing straight from the db is a better answer

Comment: @yBrodsky but Later I will count total time for every department. 
If dept = 'something' count total time else if dept = 'something2' count time etc

Comment: Still you can do it with mysql

Comment: I want to sum task_time and put it into total_time I am doing SELECT sum(task_time) AS total_time FROM `tasks_test` and it works but How can I do it for every dept?

Comment: group by deptartment

Comment: Anyway, post a properly formatted json showing how your data looks like. I think your loop is wrong.

Comment: @yBrodsky edited my question, added JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there are several problems. First of all, you are receiving an array of data which looks like this: (simplified)

```
var data = [{
  dept:"test",
  task_time:"83"
},{
  dept:"test",
  task_time:"41"
},{
  dept:"other",
  task_time:"10"
}];
```

Now, if you want to calculate how much time all the tasks took, you will do:

```
var total = 0;
angular.forEach(data, function(item) {
  total += parseFloat(item.task_time);
});

console.log(total) //will output 134
```

If you want to sum the total depending on the department, you can store them in an object like this:

```
var totalPerDept = {};
angular.forEach(data, function(item) {
  if(!totalPerDept[item.dept]) {
    totalPerDept[item.dept] = 0;
  }
  totalPerDept[item.dept] += parseFloat(item.task_time);
});
```

And then in the view you show it like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="d in data">
 Department: {{d.dept}} | Total in this dept: {{totalPerDept[d.dept]}}
</div>
```

As you can see, you are using the department name as an index to access the property of the other object.

Anyway, as I said in the comments, it would be easier to simple do all this math in the query and have it all delivered nicely.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, anyway I'll try do math in query like u said.

Comment: I checked your code and it works but I have question. Is it possible to make something like that: I have dept: test, dept: test, dept: other, dept: other. And I want to sum it like test = 20, other = 40 one time don't show test = 15 , test = 5 etc... Do you understand? :)